# Disable HTTP OPTIONS method

Tags: nginx

Recently our vulnerability scanner detected to disable the HTTP OPTION method in our Nginx server.

By referring to the Nginx document we made the below entry in the Nginx configuration file but after making the entry I restarted the Nginx service but the Nginx service failed to restart.

```
limit_except GET {
    allow 192.168.1.0/32;
    deny  all;
}
```

Can anyone help me disable the HTTP option method in the Nginx?

Comment: Your question is off-topic on SO but have a look at https://blogs.reliablepenguin.com/2019/01/02/disable-options-method-nginx